# Can you help me with web-scraping problem in Python, in which I like to scrape URLs from a page, whose pagination numbers are partially hidden?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the "URLs" of each page, as shown in the pagination, of this particular site, at https://collegedunia.com/usa/biology-colleges/page-16.

The problem I face is that the URLs of all pages are not shown at one time. For example, if you try to scrape the URLs using the link provided above, you are only able to scrape URls of page-1, page-14, page-15, and page-16. I also followed the content concerned with scraping multiple pages at https://oxylabs.io/blog/pagination-in-web-scraping, it did not help me with the problem at hand.

For example, if you run the code below, it scrapes just partial list of URls.

```
            from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
            import requests

            url = "https://collegedunia.com/usa/biology-colleges/page-16"

            headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}




            page = requests.Session().get(url, headers = headers)

            pageParse = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")

            soup = pageParse.find("ul", {'class':'jsx-3212034721 list-unstyled d-flex justify-content-center paginate text-center'})

            soupATags = soup.find_all("a")

            paginationNos = [item.text for item in soupATags]

            pageURL = [f'https://collegedunia.com{item.get("href")}'for item in soupATags]
```

This has generated the URLs successfully, but not the full complement of URLs.
So, I tried the following code, which was a bit tricky.

```
set1 = {"https://collegedunia.com/usa/biology-colleges"}

blacklistSet2 = set()

def funcCountryList(set2, set1):

    try:

        if len(set1)!=len(blacklistSet2):

            for url in set1:

                if not url in blacklistSet2:

                    page = requests.Session().get(url, headers = headers)

                    pageParse = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")

                    soup = pageParse.find("ul", {'class':'jsx-3212034721 list-unstyled d-flex justify-content-center paginate text-center'})

                    soupATags = soup.find_all("a")

                    paginationNos = [item.text for item in soupATags]

                    pageURL = [f'https://collegedunia.com{item.get("href")}'for item in soupATags]

                    for item in pageURL:

                        set1.add(item)

                    blacklistSet2.add(url)

                    funcCountryList(blacklistSet2, set1)

                else:

                    continue
        else:

            finalList.append(set1)

            return finalList

    except:

        return sorted(list(set1))

getURLS = funcCountryList(blacklistSet2, set1)

print(getURLS)
```

The latter code did scrape all the URLs, but the approach was a bit tricky. I wonder if there exists other straightforward and easier methods.

**Question:**
I would like to know if there are other ways to get all the URLs - of all pages shown in the pagination - in one go, rather than updating the iterable (containing URLs), and looping over it, until all URLs have been scraped. I would really appreciate it if you could share easier method(s) to achieve this.

Comment: If you know the pattern, why not just iterate a counter and scrape pages until you get a 404 error returned?  Alternatively, if the first pages has a link to the last page, can you not just get the page number of the last page and scrape them from first to last?

Comment: Yes, I had that idea of generating numbers b/w and including the first and the last number. The URL of the first page does not have the number included in it. For example, the URL of page 2 ends like "https://........./page-2", but for the page1 it is different. That is why I didn't want to try that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, how you could get all pages without explicitly knowing the end URL:

- in the paginator, get active page tag (with `class="active"`)
- select next sibling `<a>`
- if the sibling exists, extract the next URL from it
- if the sibling does not exist, break from the loop

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0"
}
url = "https://collegedunia.com/usa/biology-colleges"


while True:
    print()
    print(url)
    print("-" * 80)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

    # print some data from the page
    for h3 in soup.select("h3"):
        print(h3.text)

    next_page = soup.select_one(".active + li a")
    if not next_page:
        break

    url = "https://collegedunia.com" + next_page["href"]
```

Prints all pages until `page-16`:

```
...

Tarleton State University, Stephenville
University of Wisconsin, Stevens Point
Northeastern State University, Tahlequah

https://collegedunia.com/usa/biology-colleges/page-16
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nicholls State University, Thibodaux
Heidelberg University, Tiffin
Washburn University, Topeka
Troy University, Troy

...
```